# SonarQube 5.1.1 - Analysis very Slow with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

We want to use SonarQube 5.1.1 for analysing a Java-project with about 25.000 files. But the Step "Apply project exclusions" is very slow and takes 2.5 hours. Meanwhile the CPU-activity on the AIX-DB-Server is very high - 60% CPU.

When starting SonarQube-Analysis (ANT-Task) in TRACE-Mode, we can see, that the following SQLs are executed very slow. 
Every SQL needs approximately 0.5 seconds. It seems, that this SQL is executed for each of the 25.000 files.

I'm no Oracle-expert but it seems that the problem will be a "full tablescan" on the table "project_measures" for each of the 25.000 files.

Any ideas on work arounds or solutions?

I'm not sure if this is the same problem: [sonarqube-apply-project-exclusions-very-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029254/sonarqube-apply-project-exclusions-very-slow)

Log from ANT-Analyzer (TRACE-Level):

```
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.342 DEBUG - Opening JDBC Connection
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.358 DEBUG - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:XXX:XXX, UserName=SONAR, Oracle JDBC driver]
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.358 DEBUG - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:XXX:XXX, UserName=SONAR, Oracle JDBC driver]
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.358 DEBUG - Load technical debt model (done) | time=16ms
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.374 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.374 DEBUG - Opening JDBC Connection
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.389 DEBUG - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:XXX:XXX, UserName=SONAR, Oracle JDBC driver]
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.389 DEBUG - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:XXX:XXX, UserName=SONAR, Oracle JDBC driver]
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:29.592 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:32.077 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:33.295 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:34.405 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:35.108 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
[sonar:sonar] 10:59:35.733 DEBUG - select metric1_.name as col_0_0_, measuremod0_.id as col_1_0_, measuremod0_.id as id5_, measuremod0_.alert_status as alert2_5_, measuremod0_.alert_text as alert3_5_, measuremod0_.characteristic_id as characte4_5_, measuremod0_.measure_data as measure5_5_, measuremod0_.description as descript6_5_, measuremod0_.metric_id as metric7_5_, measuremod0_.person_id as person8_5_, measuremod0_.project_id as project9_5_, measuremod0_.rule_id as rule10_5_, measuremod0_.rule_priority as rule11_5_, measuremod0_.snapshot_id as snapshot12_5_, measuremod0_.tendency as tendency5_, measuremod0_.text_value as text14_5_, measuremod0_.url as url5_, measuremod0_.value as value5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_1 as variation17_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_2 as variation18_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_3 as variation19_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_4 as variation20_5_, measuremod0_.variation_value_5 as variation21_5_ from project_measures measuremod0_, metrics metric1_, projects resourcemo2_, snapshots snapshot3_ where metric1_.id=measuremod0_.metric_id and measuremod0_.snapshot_id=snapshot3_.id and snapshot3_.project_id=resourcemo2_.id and resourcemo2_.kee=? and snapshot3_.status=? and snapshot3_.qualifier<>? and (measuremod0_.characteristic_id is null) and (measuremod0_.person_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_id is null) and (measuremod0_.rule_priority is null) and (metric1_.name in (? , ? , ?)) and snapshot3_.islast=1 order by snapshot3_.created_at
```

SQL which probably causes the problem:

```
SELECT metric1_.name AS col_0_0_,
         measuremod0_.id AS col_1_0_,
         measuremod0_.id AS id5_,
         measuremod0_.alert_status AS alert2_5_,
         measuremod0_.alert_text AS alert3_5_,
         measuremod0_.characteristic_id AS characte4_5_,
         measuremod0_.measure_data AS measure5_5_,
         measuremod0_.description AS descript6_5_,
         measuremod0_.metric_id AS metric7_5_,
         measuremod0_.person_id AS person8_5_,
         measuremod0_.project_id AS project9_5_,
         measuremod0_.rule_id AS rule10_5_,
         measuremod0_.rule_priority AS rule11_5_,
         measuremod0_.snapshot_id AS snapshot12_5_,
         measuremod0_.tendency AS tendency5_,
         measuremod0_.text_value AS text14_5_,
         measuremod0_.url AS url5_,
         measuremod0_.VALUE AS value5_,
         measuremod0_.variation_value_1 AS variation17_5_,
         measuremod0_.variation_value_2 AS variation18_5_,
         measuremod0_.variation_value_3 AS variation19_5_,
         measuremod0_.variation_value_4 AS variation20_5_,
         measuremod0_.variation_value_5 AS variation21_5_
    FROM project_measures measuremod0_,
         metrics metric1_,
         projects resourcemo2_,
         snapshots snapshot3_
   WHERE     metric1_.id = measuremod0_.metric_id
         AND measuremod0_.snapshot_id = snapshot3_.id
         AND snapshot3_.project_id = resourcemo2_.id
         AND resourcemo2_.kee = :1
         AND snapshot3_.status = :2
         AND snapshot3_.qualifier <> :3
         AND (measuremod0_.characteristic_id IS NULL)
         AND (measuremod0_.person_id IS NULL)
         AND (measuremod0_.rule_id IS NULL)
         AND (measuremod0_.rule_priority IS NULL)
         AND (metric1_.name IN ( :4, :5, :6))
         AND snapshot3_.islast = 1
ORDER BY snapshot3_.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just a few point that might help you. AFAIK nobody can help you, since you did not provide enough information

- contact your DBAs ask them for cooperation
- start problem investigation from the other(DB) side. Generate AWR/Statspack report and you will see. Generally Oracle offer mighty performance analysis tools, when compared with Java.
- get execution plan for the query
- Oracle indexes by default do not index NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not from SonarSource, but it looks like the ticket you pointed so I believe 5.2 would be the solution.

In the meanwhile, some points from the Oracle DB side:

1. Are you using a dedicated tablespace for the SonarQube user? See http://qualilogy.com/en/install-sonar-oracle-user/ on my blog. If you are using a tablespace shared with other Oracle users/dbs, especially on a virtual server, then you are more prone to get performance problems.
2. Check that the tablespace is big enough from the start and with an 'autorextended' parameter high enough too. If the tablespace needs to grow, and do it by small increments, then Oracle is working more on constantly adding some little space.
3. Check also other system tablespaces, especially the one dedicated to indexes. The bigger and the older it is, the less performance you will have.

Again, I don't think this will solve your problem, but it might help, or at least, it might be good to remember if you are operating SonarQube with Oracle.

Best regards.

Comment: Nice tutorials. P/S: could edit your post? Make an ```enter``` after ```Oracle DB side:``` for friendly view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I could not find the 'Oracle DB side', could you point on where it does not display well in the post? It might depend on the browser, especially that the Wordpress template I am using is very old.

Comment: ```Oracle DB side: 1. Are you using``` You need a line after the ```:```

Comment: Ohh, Ok. I thought you were speaking about my post. I have to make a double 'enter' in order to have the list correct.

Answer (score 0):

For any update on this performance issue, please watch, vote or comment the following Jira ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6839