# Sonar runner is very slow during "apply project exclusions"

Tags: performance, sonarqube

I´m facing the same problems as described here: [sonarqube "Apply project exclusions" very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029254/sonarqube-apply-project-exclusions-very-slow)

[image]

Is this already solved? Are there any workarounds in the meantime? We measure dozens of projects in the night so it´s really problematic if only one scan last that long (see screenshot).

We are using Sonar 5.1 with Oracle 11g.

Regards Harald

Comment: see latest comment on the question you are refering to. no planned fix for this in 5.1.

Comment: Can you tell us when it is planned to be solved?

Comment: Ticket created : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6839, for any further discussions on this subject, would be better to simply comment this Jira ticket. By the way, could you relaunch the analysis with the parameter 'sonar.verbose=true' to make sure that you're facing the same issue that the one described in SONAR-6839 ? Thanks